# verificar que una clase o método esté definido en crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

Estoy usando el módulo **[spec](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.21.1/Spec.html)** en crystal para realizar pruebas unitarias y no hallo un equivalente de mi código en Ruby.

De momento he intentado esto

```
defined?Stream.should eq "constant"
defined?naturalNumbers.head.should eq "method"
```

pero me arroja el error

> unexpected token: Stream
>
> defined?Stream.should eq "constant"

Mi código en Ruby es

```
Test.assert_equals(defined?Stream,"constant", "Stream is not defined")
```

¿Cuál es el equivalente de la función "defined?" de Ruby en Crystal? o en su defecto... ¿Cómo puedo verificar que una clase o método esté definido en el lenguaje de programación Crystal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal es un lenguaje con chequeo estático de tipos, por lo que la forma de probar si una clase está definida o no es, simplemente, ver si compila o no un programa que la referencia.

Los tests de Ruby y otros lenguajes dinámicos que preguntan por *la forma* de una estructura/clase/objeto son, en esencia, una respuesta a la falta de un chequeo de tipos: como el compilador no chequea qué miembros tiene la variable que quiero usar, escribo los tests que chequean que existan las cosas que pienso usar. Así que ese test no tiene *demasiado* sentido *per se* en Crystal (y tantos otros lenguajes con chequeo estático de tipos).

Dicho esto, en Crystal existe el pseudo-método [`responds_to?`](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/responds_to.html), que te dice si un objeto responde a un mensaje o no. No te va a servir para determinar si existe una clase determinada o no, pero sí podés preguntar si un objeto entiende determinado mensaje (aka, si tiene implementado determinado método).

```
naturalNumbers.responds_to?(:head).should be_true
```

Pero, dado que el compilador nos resuelve ese problema de los tipos, se vuelve mucho más interesante invertir ese tiempo en probar *el comportamiento* de esos objetos y métodos:

```
naturalNumbers = # ... instancia un naturalNumbers ...
naturalNumbers.head.should eq( ... )
```